# pretty logging in jooq

Tags: java, sql, logging, jooq

My task was to create a log builder for jooq routines.
I started by googling around and ended up using this: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/

In the given example author uses the available out of the box

```
DSL.using(configuration).renderInlined(ctx.routine());
```

This looked promising, but wasn't enough, because jooq didnt show field names in routines, just values. The outcome was hard to understand with bigger routines. I tried playing around with other possibilities, but to no avail...

I wrote my own log formatter, which even works. *For now :)*

**So here comes my problem: It works only for results.**

Why? Because I can only access `ctx.routine().getReturnValue()`. `ctx.routine().getInValues()` is protected.

**So here come some questions: why `getInValues()` is protected? Can it be changed to public? Or maybe there is a workaround for this...?**

As a workaround I tried using reflection, which shows another problem.  **`getReturnValue()` gives me an `UDTRecord`, which has `intoMap()` method returning `Map<String, Object>`. `getInValues` returns `Map<Parameter<?>, Field<?>>`. I have no idea how to work with the latter...** I decided not to mess with the whole library and ask my questions here :)

looking forward for your responses

Best regards

edit: pasting the first draft of my code below. maybe it will help you understand what am i trying to achieve.

```
import org.jooq.*;
import org.jooq.impl.*;

import java.util.Map;

public class OutputLogBuilder
{
  private final static String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  private final static String TAB = "\t";
  private final static String COL_RECORD_SEPARATOR = " --> ";

  static String buildOutputLog(final ExecuteContext ctx)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(NEW_LINE);
    handleUDTRecord(sb, ctx.routine().getReturnValue(), 0);

    return sb.toString();
  }

  private static void handleUDTRecord(final StringBuilder sb, final Object input, int depth)
  {
    UDTRecordImpl record = (UDTRecordImpl) input;
    appendData(sb, record.getUDT().getName(), "", depth);
    depth++;

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : record.intoMap().entrySet()) {
      String entryKey = entry.getKey();
      Object entryValue = entry.getValue();

      if (isArrayUDTRecord(entryValue)) {
        handleArrayUDTRecord(sb, entryValue, depth);
      } else if (isUDTRecord(entryValue)) {
        handleUDTRecord(sb, entryValue, depth);
      } else {
        appendData(sb, entryKey, entryValue, depth);
      }
    }
  }

  private static boolean isArrayUDTRecord(final Object object)
  {
    return object instanceof ArrayRecordImpl;
  }

  private static boolean isUDTRecord(final Object object)
  {
    return object instanceof UDTRecordImpl;
  }

  private static void handleArrayUDTRecord(final StringBuilder sb, final Object input, int depth)
  {
    ArrayRecordImpl arrayRecord = (ArrayRecordImpl) input;
    appendData(sb, arrayRecord.getName(), "", depth);
    depth++;

    for (Object arrayElement : arrayRecord.getList()) {
      if (isArrayUDTRecord(arrayElement)) {
        handleArrayUDTRecord(sb, arrayElement, depth);
      } else if (isUDTRecord(arrayElement)) {
        handleUDTRecord(sb, arrayElement, depth);
      } else {
        appendData(sb, input, "", depth);
      }
    }
  }

  private static void appendData(final StringBuilder sb, final Object key, final Object value, int depth)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
      sb.append(TAB);
    }
    sb.append(key + COL_RECORD_SEPARATOR + value);
    sb.append(NEW_LINE);
  }
}
```

edit2: With reflection I managed to figure out how to build my log with `AbstractParam`, `UDTConstant` and such, but they are package protected... 
below is the sample code snippet to check the type of elements

```
for (Map.Entry<Parameter<?>, Field<?>> entry : inValues.entrySet()) {
  Parameter entryKey = entry.getKey();
  Field entryValue = entry.getValue();
  if(entryValue instanceof UDTConstant){ //access error
    //do smth
  }
}
```

so whenever i check their type I get
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.jooq.impl.UDTConstant from class org.jooq.impl.OutputLogBuilder`
even though (as u can see) i placed my code it in the same package...
so again - why are those classes NOT public? can it be changed? is there any workaround?

Comment: @Lukas Eder - any ideas? : )

Comment: [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31389243/521799). Although, your own answer is better, so you could actually move that part of your question and answer your own question, here on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is essentially this missing feature:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4109

The [`Routine`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Routine.html) API is simply not sophisticated enough for what you're trying to do. Any workaround (e.g. using reflection) or patching the sources will have to do for now.

Comment: thx for the answer. ps. it feels a bit weird to answer my own question, so I just accepter your answer :)

Comment: @WrRaThY: [It isn't weird at all](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I've done it numerous times myself, so go ahead! In fact, it's even better than editing your question with a partial solution, because having a solution in a question is uncommon on Stack Overflow